# Optimizing an arbitrary function of 10 variables

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming

Let us be given a function $f(x_1,\dots,x_{10})$ of multiple variables $x_1,\dots,x_{10}$ given that $\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i \leq 7$. How do we solve the following problem?

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\{x_i\}, i=1,\dots,10} \quad & f(x_1,\dots,x_{10})\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i \leq 7\\
  & x_i \in X_i, X_i = [0,10]    \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

I with my professor are trying to work on building a neural network in such a way that we have multiple output from each layer. For example there are $n$ neurons in the $i^{th}$ layer, there will be, let us say $k$ outputs of each size $n$. Similarly, the next layer will also have same number of output and we will look at all the possible ways to connect $k$ outputs of the $i^{th}$ layer and $k$ outputs of the $(i+1)^{st}$ layer. And we take the max of the output in each layer while updating the loss function. My professor told me that this boils down to finally become a DP problem.

Comment: Any additional information, such as *the contribution of each $x_i$ is independent of all $x_j, j\ne i$* or *all $x_i$s are integral*?

Comment: If the variables are integers, there are only 19448 options to try.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to indicate whether the variables must be integers, or if not, what domain they come from.

Comment: "$k$ outputs of each size $n$": what ??

Comment: If all $X_i$ are identical, why $i$ ? And due to the sum and positiveness constraints, $x_i\le 7$ must hold anyway.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It means that each layer can be parallelized. So, the weights should go from $i^{th}$ layer (of size $(n,1)$) to multiple copies of $(i+1)^{st}$ layer. This way, instead of getting one output from $(i+1)^{st}$ layer, we will get multiple outputs (say $k$ outputs) of each size $(n,1)$

Comment: @Siddhartha: what do you mean by $(n,1)$ ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust A column vector of dimension $n$.

Comment: There are no matrices in your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 19448 combinations of $x$'s that meet the constraints.  If $f$ is arbitrary, the best you can do is enumerate all 19448 combinations and see which leads to the largest value of $f$.  There is no faster algorithm.  Dynamic programming does not seem relevant.

If you know something about the structure of $f$ (e.g., it is a separable function), then it might be possible to do better.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a dynamic programming solution. I highly doubt there is one (especially, a polynomial time).